# Php Single page form processing issue

Tags: php

(Sorry for my bad english)

Well, I've 3 errors in my code.

Error's:

1. First of all it's show : Notice: Undefined index: form in C:\xampp\htdocs\evantechbd\index.php on line 461. When i run this form.
2. if any error found it's show error message, well, but correct field is empty. Example: In this form there is 4 fields. a) upload image, b) select discussion c) subject and d) message. Suppose you upload a image, select a discussion and write a subject but forgot to write message. Then It's show "Message Required" and every filed is empty. I don't want empty field which is correct.
3. After successfully submitted the form it's show "Discussion was submitted ". But after that if i refresh the page it's send the data to database. But I did not click submit button. why this happen?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['form'] == "Submit") {
    $err       = array();
    $filed     = addslashes($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    $img_named = addslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $img_type  = addslashes($_FILES['file']['type']);
    @$imgd = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));

    function getExtension($str)
    {
        $i = strrpos($str, ".");
        if (!$i) {
            return "";
        }
        $l   = strlen($str) - $i;
        $ext = substr($str, $i + 1, $l);
        return $ext;
    }
    $extension        = getExtension($img_named);
    $extension        = strtolower($extension);
    $image_named_uniq = uniqid() . '.' . $extension;
    $upload_path_dis  = 'user/manage/discussionimg/';

    $diss = $_POST['type'];
    $sub  = $_POST['sub'];
    $msg  = $_POST['msg'];
    $date = "On " . date("F Y h:i:s A");

    if (!isset($_SESSION['uname']))
        $err[] = "You need to login";

    else {
        $uname = $_SESSION['uname']; //session username

        if (empty($sub) && empty($msg) && empty($filed))
            $err[] = "All field required";
        else {
            if (empty($sub))
                $err[] = "Subject Requried";

            if (empty($msg))
                $err[] = "Message Requried";

            if (empty($filed))
                $err[] = "SORRY, you have to be upload a image";
        }
    }

    if (!empty($err)) {
        foreach ($err as $er) {
            echo "<font color=red>$er</font><br/>";
        }
    }

    else {
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO discussion VALUES ('', '$imgd', '$image_named_uniq', 
'$diss', '$sub', '$msg', '$uname', '$date' ) ");
        if (!$sql)
            echo "Can't submit your discussion" . mysql_error();

        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $upload_path_dis . $image_named_uniq)) {
            die('File Not Uploading');
        } else {
            echo "Discussion was submitted";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Many Thanks for your help!!
Kanta.

Comment: You really need indents. First off i see this `if ($_POST['form']== "Submit")
{   `, wheres the ending brace?

Comment: You report an errors on line 261 - yet your code only has 120 lines - what line reports the error ?

Comment: Formatted best I can ... a function in an if statement is that legal ?

Comment: @ManseUK: absolutely legal. Usually, for backward compatibility: `if(!function_exists('base64_encode')){ function base64_encode(){} }`

Comment: @ManseUk,  there are also many code, but i just put only form processing code

Comment: Is there anyone can tell me what is the wrong in my code

Comment: @ManseUK, Here is my full code. http://www.dawamedical.com/index.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try changing your first if condition as follows

   `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`
2. Now most of web sites uses client side validations using javascript. You can use jquery frame work to make things easier. However since you already uses validations after the POST event. You have to set values to relevant fields as bellow code. It will set tha value of the subject.

   `<input type="text" name="sub" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["sub"]))  echo $_POST["sub"];  ?>" size="46"/>`
3. Yes if you refresh the code it will again do the post and insert.  You have to do few controls. However these things depend on your data.

a. Make unique key indexes in the database

b. Check for existing record before the insertion.

c. Redirect your page to the same page after few seconds once the user see the successful message.

Comment: Doing only client side validation isn't the best thing to go on. You always need server side validation, because you simply can bypass client side validation, which could result in strange effects. Always do both. Client side is nice for the user to see the errors before submitting the form.

Comment: Yes agree. Both validation are require. What I needed to say is if you need to do this perfectly you have to use javascript validations. If you use only server side validations the client only see errors after filling and submitting all the details.